# Simple php regex using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to change strings with the odd "`&quot;`" such as:

```
He said: &quot;I don't think so&quot;
```

To be:

```
He said: "I don't think so"
```

My current code is:

```
$sentence = addslashes(preg_replace('/^\&quot\;$/','\"',$var));
```

What is my problem in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` and `$` will only match the start and end of the whole string (or a whole line in `/m` mode). Since `&quot;` doesn't appear like that, your regex whole match it. Just remove the `^` and `$` and it should work.

BTW, perhaps you want to use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off using PHPs `htmlspecialchars_decode()`:

```
$var = "He said: &quot;I don't think so&quot;";
$sentence = htmlspecialchars_decode($var);
```

Answer (score 1):

This one may solve your problem:

```
$yourstring = "He said: &quot;I don't think so&quot;";
$newstring = str_replace("&quot;","\"",$yourstring);

echo $newstring;
```

Comment: +1 for noting that the target is a fixed length literal string. For this case `str_replace()` will be faster than `preg_replace()`.